# Caption above longtable in multiply pages

Tags: longtable

Hi I want to set the caption above the longtable, but it doesn't work. Now I have this code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,listof=entryprefix,listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{babel}                  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[4]
    \begin{longtable}{l|c|c|p{5.85cm}}
        \caption{Adressbereiche der Modbus-Datenübertragung}\label{tab:adressbereich_modbus}\\
        \endfirsthead
        \caption*{Tabelle \ref{tab:adressbereich_modbus} fortgeführt: Adressbereiche der Modbus-Datenübertragung}\\
        \textbf{Objekttyp}  & \textbf{Zugriff} & \textbf{Größe} & \textbf{Funktionscode} \\
        \hline \hline
        \endhead
        %
        Binäre Ausgänge  & Lesen \& & 1 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 01: Lese Ausgangsbit Status \\ 
        Coil&Schreiben&& $\cdot$ FC 05: Schreibe Ausgangsbit \\
        &&& $\cdot$ FC 15: Schreibe mehrfach Ausgangsbit \\
        \hline
        Binäre Eingänge  & Lesen               & 1 Bit      & $\cdot$ FC 02: Lese Eingangsbit Status \\
        Discrete Input&&&\\
        \hline
        Analoge Eingänge & Lesen               & 16 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 04: Lese Input-Register \\
        Input Register&&&\\
        \hline
        Analoge Ausgänge & Lesen \&  & 16 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 03: Lese Holding-Register \\
        Holding Register&Schreiben&& $\cdot\,\,$FC 06: Schreibe Holding-Register \\
        &&& $\cdot\,\,$FC 16: Schreibe mehrfach Holding-Register \\
        \hline
        \hline       
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

With this output:
[image]

I don't know why it destroys my first header. Have anyone an idea? And can I set a distance between the tabular (or longtable) and this caption? Thank you!

Comment: what di you mean by "destroy" here? If you mean no bold entries in the cells you have not got any column headings in your first head. You can use `\\[3cm]` after the caption to add more space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the bold column titles to appear in the first head too, you have to write them there as well, if that is what you meant by 'destroy'. And for setting the captions above tables neatly with some extra space, KOMA classes (like `scrartcl` you're using) offers the option `captions=tableheading`.

Is this the style you are after?

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,listof=entryprefix,listof=totoc,captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{babel}                  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[4]
    \begin{longtable}{l|c|c|p{5.85cm}}
        \caption{Adressbereiche der Modbus-Datenübertragung}\label{tab:adressbereich_modbus}\\
        \textbf{Objekttyp}  & \textbf{Zugriff} & \textbf{Größe} & \textbf{Funktionscode} \\
        \hline \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption*{Tabelle \ref{tab:adressbereich_modbus} fortgeführt: Adressbereiche der Modbus-Datenübertragung}\\
        \textbf{Objekttyp}  & \textbf{Zugriff} & \textbf{Größe} & \textbf{Funktionscode} \\
        \hline \hline
        \endhead
        %
        Binäre Ausgänge  & Lesen \& & 1 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 01: Lese Ausgangsbit Status \\ 
        Coil&Schreiben&& $\cdot$ FC 05: Schreibe Ausgangsbit \\
        &&& $\cdot$ FC 15: Schreibe mehrfach Ausgangsbit \\
        \hline
        Binäre Eingänge  & Lesen               & 1 Bit      & $\cdot$ FC 02: Lese Eingangsbit Status \\
        Discrete Input&&&\\
        \hline
        Analoge Eingänge & Lesen               & 16 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 04: Lese Input-Register \\
        Input Register&&&\\
        \hline
        Analoge Ausgänge & Lesen \&  & 16 Bit     & $\cdot$ FC 03: Lese Holding-Register \\
        Holding Register&Schreiben&& $\cdot\,\,$FC 06: Schreibe Holding-Register \\
        &&& $\cdot\,\,$FC 16: Schreibe mehrfach Holding-Register \\
        \hline
        \hline       
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```